# Can't access Rest Api written in Java which is hosted in Windows Server 2012 (Azure)

Tags: windows, java

I Can't access Rest Api calls written in Java which is hosted in Windows Server 2012 (Azure) in apache server.

Within the virtual machine i can access through fiddler/browser and get the data.
But outside the virtual machine specifiying the dns name or using ip address instead of localhost i am not getting the data.
I have opened 8080 port on azure portal. It gives 502 error message.

Is there any other configurations needs to be done